# php read web page contents

Tags: php

i want to create a server for push notifications (ios) .this server every 1 minute read the contents of a web page and check for changes of matches results,if changes was found then send alerts to apple push notification server (apns) with the name of the clubs an scors.

Example can someone check this [link](http://www.goalzz.com/main.aspx?region=-1&area=6)
 and tell me if is this possible .
sory of my english.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It'll be a decent chunk of work.

Comment: You can certainly have some scheduled process (such as a cron job) make a request to an external service (or site), check some data, and respond to that data in some way (push a notification to another service).  Does the target site have any kind of API for accessing the data directly?  Or do you have to use the web interface alone?  If the latter, what you're looking to do is called "screen scraping."  Tools like Curl allow you to get the page text, and DOM parsers will help you pull the data out of that blob of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

Any solution you make will be specific to **that page** only. There are no general solutions. Also, if the page layout were to change someday, you will have to rewrite the entire code.

Writing code to check content of a page in which there are no guarantees (of content or layout) is risky.

Comment: thanks for the answer.For me, I do not understand anything in php,and can you Suggests at some tutorial

Comment: Try [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html) website. It has detailed tutorials that will help you master the basics. Good luck.